# F# multiple when guards using grouping patterns in pattern matching

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

why this code does not work, and how to make it work?

```
let id1 = 0
match p1, p2 with
  | Fluid, Particle id2 when id = id2
  | Interface _, Particle id2 when id = id2 -> doSomething()
  ...
```

So is it possible to have several when guards in pattern groups?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only have one when guard per arrow/result, so something like this would work:

```
let id1 = 0

match p1, p2 with
| Fluid, Particle id2
| Interface _, Particle id2 when id1 = id2 -> doSomething()
| _ ->  doSomething()
```

(note in this case both items in the or must bind the same set of identifiers so that in either case no identifer is left uninitialized)

or alternatively add a second action/result:

```
match p1, p2 with
| Fluid, Particle id2 when id1 = id2 -> doSomething()
| Interface _, Particle id2 when id1 = id2 -> doSomething()
| _ ->  doSomething()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is good to know that the when guard is valid for all cases in the pattern group.